# SELECT による表示で、column を指定したらちゃんと表示されるのに、* で全体を出力したら表示が狂う

Tags: mysql

次のような、csvファイル(books.csv, Excel で作成)から

```
mysql> load data infile 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\books.csv' into table books
-> fields terminated by ','
-> lines terminated by '\n'
-> ignore 1 rows
-> ;
```

のコマンドで読み込んだ table (名前は books )があります。

```
id,title,author,genre,height,publisher
1,Fundamentals of Wavelets,Goswami Jaideva,signal_processing,228,Wiley
2,Data Smart,Foreman John,data_science,235,Wiley
3,God Created the Integers,Hawking Stephen,mathematics,197,Penguin
4,Superfreakonomics,Dubner Stephen,economics,179,HarperCollins
5,Orientalism,Said Edward,history,197,Penguin
```

これを

```
mysql> SELECT id, title FROM books;
```

で出力したら

[image: column を指定した場合の出力]

ときれいに表示されるのですが、

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM books;
```

と全体を表示すると

[image: 全体を表示した場合]

と乱れてしまいます。なぜでしょうか。
MySQL 8.0 です。

-- 補足 --

```
mysql> SELECT id, publisher FROM books;
```

では次のようになります。
[image: id, publisher を指定した場合]

縦表示では次のようになります
[image: 縦表示]

また、

```
mysql> DESC books
```

による出力は次のようになります。
[image: DESC books による出力]

Comment: SELECT id, publisher from books;だとどんな表示になりますか

Comment: コメントでは画像を貼れないみたい（？）なので質問を編集しました。

Comment: 上記となるのであれば、publisherカラムのデータに画面表示を乱す制御文字が含まれているのではないでしょうか？'\r'や'\n'などが含まれていませんか？

Comment: カラムごとの表示や、CSV に一度出力してみると何かわかるかもしれません。 参考: [MySQLのクエリ結果を整形、縦表示やCSV出力で見やすくする方法](https://サーバー構築と設定.com/?p=1631)

Comment: csv に出力するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

Comment: CSVファイルからデータをインポートする際の `load data infile ...` ですが、`ENCLOSED BY '"'` を指定する必要がありそうです(一部の書籍のタイトルが Excel 上では複数行になっている様に見えます)。また、Excel の CSV エクスポートの設定次第になるかと思いますが、`LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` の部分はもしかすると `\r\n` にする必要があるかもしれません。

Comment: (`ENCLOSED BY '"'` は必要なく)
`lines terminated by '\r\n'` により解決できました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lines terminated by '\n'`

→ `lines terminated by '\r\n'` により解決できました。